# Receiving past events after clear FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE

Tags: android

I have an activity in which I want to avoid the user touch buttons during a time.

I make this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

It works great, but when I come back to receive touch events with:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

I receive all the events relatives to the user touchs during the period not touchable.

Any idea how to discard this events?

Comment: You have solved this problem yet?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember if I solved it, or I found other way to do what I needed

Comment: OK, thanks! I have solved this problem by set enable = false to all views and versa while don't needed!

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem but I come up with a workaround without messing up with window flag.
Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev){
    if(activityTouchable == false)return true;
    else return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEvent event){
    if(activityTouchable == false)return true;
    else return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```